# How to use bootstrap4.0.0-beta to setup a layout for all width

Tags: breakpoints, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap4.0.0-beta to build a website.
Because the designer who design this site only design one layout, the container width is 1070px. So I'm trying to use this one layout for all breakpoint, that means no matter the device width, it will only show one layout.
What I do now is remove the line:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and set `.container` width to 1100px, but it doesn't work, when the browser width change, the .container still changing.

How should I make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a few hours research, find a way to do it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500">
```

if the webpage needs at least 500px to show, in my case, I will use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
```